# Sound Settings Crashes after setting up Simultaneous Output with paprefs

Tags: settings, sound, audio, crash, bugs

I am using elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera

I want to use two audio output devices simultaneously. They are different physical cards. one is a usb dac and one is the built in line-out

When i select simultaneous output devices in paprefs (https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices) sound settings crashes every time i open it.

Sound settings pops up for a second then vanishes. Sound still works but through the previously selected output.

To test, i loaded Ubuntu 20.x onto a small partition and followed the same paprefs process and it worked fine - i was able to select the simultaneous virtual device in Ubuntu sound settings.

Do i have to manually configure an audio sink and point the os at it via pulseaudio terminal commands? Is this possible?

Thank you for your help here